# Shuffle Array images in android

Tags: android, gridview, random

I am developing an Android application where I need to shuffle images that are stored in an array using a random function before assigning to an adapter. 
I have the following code on how to shuffle the array images, but it encounters an error

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context ctx;
    boolean flage=false;
    int img1=-1,img2=-1;
    public int OriginalArray[] = { R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        shuffleArray();
        final GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_memory);
        grid.setAdapter(new GridViewContent(this));
    }
    private void shuffleArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random arrayRandom= new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<OriginalArray.length-1; i++){
            int index=arrayRandom.nextInt(i);
            OriginalArray[i]=OriginalArray[index];

        }

    }
    public class GridViewContent extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        public int pictureArray[]={
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,
                R.drawable.question,        
        };
        public GridViewContent(Context c){
            context=c;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (pictureArray.length);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return pictureArray[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ImageView myimage=new ImageView(context);
            myimage.setImageResource(pictureArray[position]);
            myimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            myimage.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
            myimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myimage.setImageResource(OriginalArray[position]);

                if(flage==false)
                {

                img1=OriginalArray[position];

                flage=true;

                }else if(flage==true){

                img2=OriginalArray[position];
                checkResult();
                flage=false;
                }
                //else if(f)
                }
            });

            return myimage;
        }

    }
    public void checkResult() {
        if(img1==img2)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congratualatin !!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_memory);
            grid.setAdapter(new GridViewContent(this));
        }

    }
}
```

LogCat......

```
03-12 05:40:31.904: D/dalvikvm(1081): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 8% free 2771K/3000K, paused 198ms, total 201ms
03-12 05:40:31.914: I/dalvikvm-heap(1081): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.943MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-12 05:40:31.965: D/dalvikvm(1081): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3870K/4104K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
03-12 05:40:32.014: D/AndroidRuntime(1081): Shutting down VM
03-12 05:40:32.014: W/dalvikvm(1081): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.memoryforkids/com.example.memoryforkids.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:175)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.example.memoryforkids.MainActivity.shuffArray(MainActivity.java:47)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.example.memoryforkids.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-12 05:40:32.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are using same drawable in Array so why are you shuffling??

Comment: see Collections.shuffle

Comment: @kalyanpvs: actually i use this code for kids game and i want that each time position of image change..

Comment: ok..instead of Arrays use ArrayList and Collections.shuffle  for shuffle data..

Comment: @kalyanpvs: Sir if u send me  a sample  code i will be very thankfull to u....

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman ok..wait i will post.

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman posted do like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert you array into arraylist and then you can apply `Collection.shuffle()` on it.

Here below lines convert your `int` array of pictures into arraylist of `Integer`.

```
List<Integer> pictures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int index = 0; index < OriginalArray.length; index++)
{
    pictures.add(OriginalArray[index]);
}
```

Then use `Collection.shuffle()` on it.

```
Collections.shuffle(pictures);
```

And now in your `getView` method you can use it by following way.

```
myimage.setImageResource(pictures.get(position));
```